# certmonger save chained certificate for nginx

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, pki, dogtags, certmonger

We use certmonger to issue certs for backend systems, this works fine for apache but with nginx I must specify a chained cert.

```
getcert request -f /etc/pki/tls/certs/$(hostname).crt -k /etc/pki/tls/private/$(hostname).key -r -F /etc/pki/tls/certs/intermediate.crt
```

Opt 1) Can I have certmonger save the certificate in both formats? (Preferred)

Opt 2) Can I tell nginx to chain the certs for me. (similar to how apache does)

I want to avoid writing a script, but if I must that's fine.

Example:

**/etc/pki/tls/certs/$(hostname).crt**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIHHjCCBgagAwIBAgIQDhG71w1UtxDQxvVAtrUspDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBw
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3
d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMS8wLQYDVQQDEyZEaWdpQ2VydCBTSEEyIEhpZ2ggQXNz
dXJhbmNlIFNlcnZlciBDQTAeFw0xNjA1MjEwMDAwMDBaFw0xOTA4MTQxMjAwMDBa
MGoxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQswCQYDVQQIEwJOWTERMA8GA1UEBxMITmV3IFlvcmsx
HTAbBgNVBAoTFFN0YWNrIEV4Y2hhbmdlLCBJbmMuMRwwGgYDVQQDDBMqLnN0YWNr
ZXhjaGFuZ2UuY29tMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAr0YD
zscT5i6T2FaRsTGNCiLB8OtPXu8N9iAyuaROh/nS0kRRsN8wUMk1TmgZhPuYM6oF
S377V8W2LqhLBMrPXi7lnhvKt2DFWCyw38RrDbEsM5dzVGErmhux3F0QqcTI92zj
VW61DmE7NSQLiR4yonVpTpdAaO4jSPJxn8d+4p1sIlU2JGSk8LZSWFqaROc7KtXt
lWP4HahNRZtdwvL5dIEGGNWx+7B+XVAfY1ygc/UisldkA+a3D2+3WAtXgFZRZZ/1
CWFjKWJNMAI6ZBAtlbgSNgRYxdcdleIhPLCzkzWysfltfiBmsmgz6VCoFR4KgJo8
Gd3MeTWojBthM10SLwIDAQABo4IDuDCCA7QwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUUWj/kK8CB3U8
zNllZGKiErhZcjswHQYDVR0OBBYEFFrBQmPCYhOznZSEqjIeF8tto4Z7MIIB6AYD
VR0RBIIB3zCCAduCEyouc3RhY2tleGNoYW5nZS5jb22CEXN0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cu
Y29tghMqLnN0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29tgg1zdGFja2F1dGguY29tggtzc3RhdGlj
Lm5ldIINKi5zc3RhdGljLm5ldIIPc2VydmVyZmF1bHQuY29tghEqLnNlcnZlcmZh
dWx0LmNvbYINc3VwZXJ1c2VyLmNvbYIPKi5zdXBlcnVzZXIuY29tgg1zdGFja2Fw
cHMuY29tghRvcGVuaWQuc3RhY2thdXRoLmNvbYIRc3RhY2tleGNoYW5nZS5jb22C
GCoubWV0YS5zdGFja2V4Y2hhbmdlLmNvbYIWbWV0YS5zdGFja2V4Y2hhbmdlLmNv
bYIQbWF0aG92ZXJmbG93Lm5ldIISKi5tYXRob3ZlcmZsb3cubmV0gg1hc2t1YnVu
dHUuY29tgg8qLmFza3VidW50dS5jb22CEXN0YWNrc25pcHBldHMubmV0ghIqLmJs
b2dvdmVyZmxvdy5jb22CEGJsb2dvdmVyZmxvdy5jb22CGCoubWV0YS5zdGFja292
ZXJmbG93LmNvbYIVKi5zdGFja292ZXJmbG93LmVtYWlsghNzdGFja292ZXJmbG93
LmVtYWlsMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIFoDAdBgNVHSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAQYIKwYB
BQUHAwIwdQYDVR0fBG4wbDA0oDKgMIYuaHR0cDovL2NybDMuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29t
L3NoYTItaGEtc2VydmVyLWc1LmNybDA0oDKgMIYuaHR0cDovL2NybDQuZGlnaWNl
cnQuY29tL3NoYTItaGEtc2VydmVyLWc1LmNybDBMBgNVHSAERTBDMDcGCWCGSAGG
/WwBATAqMCgGCCsGAQUFBwIBFhxodHRwczovL3d3dy5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vQ1BT
MAgGBmeBDAECAjCBgwYIKwYBBQUHAQEEdzB1MCQGCCsGAQUFBzABhhhodHRwOi8v
b2NzcC5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20wTQYIKwYBBQUHMAKGQWh0dHA6Ly9jYWNlcnRzLmRp
Z2ljZXJ0LmNvbS9EaWdpQ2VydFNIQTJIaWdoQXNzdXJhbmNlU2VydmVyQ0EuY3J0
MAwGA1UdEwEB/wQCMAAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAAzJAMGSdKoX1frdqNlN
iXu8Gcbsm/DxWMXpcTXlZn8s+/qQQoc+/3o0CK3C8/j9n5DmsYa88P6Ntt5ysDs+
b0ynXFva4CAEyKaoPM4SIpOjwfWBRSUOqAIkQO2/LhKBwT/EnpaIHIKGnI0UdXLQ
oDfkMDg6mgJsEBsKdKF5EfEX7iU3NO5xVJPJE8/R0btLAdYwxB9S6fSpCXGe2HqQ
D101O/7/4MWNdFSbfdDSFcn5oEm+idimrqiNrF5knmuJy4qPBkL7thNuGK6rvYCF
ZJM03ZEZhkQmn2jG/7LgjfwZmvfcITeADCpylf88bL+lf+vxe6cCl9CyqWgBDpsI
xpE=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**and /etc/pki/tls/certs/intermediate.crt**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**But I need them chained.**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**And since it's using dogtags, I would like it to autorenew.**

Comment: AFAIK Apache will also accept the chained certificate, at least in 2.4.

Comment: correct, but I need the reverse, or a way to make the chain cert from certmonger.

Comment: You can do it yourself easily enough. `cat hostname.crt intermediate.crt > chained.crt`

Comment: yes I know how to combine them, for some reason adding that as the post-save command doesn't create the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, the answer is **Selinux**.

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1484834941.587:22023): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=21252 comm="certmonger" name="after.sh" dev="dm-0" ino=244 scontext=system_u:system_r:certmonger_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1484834941.587:22023): arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=no exit=-13 a0=7f3d5b2bdb10 a1=7f3d5b2bda90 a2=7f3d5b2c08c0 a3=7f3d57f932e0 items=0 ppid=3219 pid=21252 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="certmonger" exe="/usr/sbin/certmonger" subj=system_u:system_r:certmonger_t:s0 key=(null)
```

A script is fine, just need to add before/after commands.

```
sudo ipa-getcert request -f /etc/pki/tls/certs/$(hostname).crt -k /etc/pki/tls/private/$(hostname).key -r -F /etc/pki/tls/certs/intermediate.crt -B /temp/before.sh -C /temp/after.sh
```